# Getting parameters of the best model with crossvalidation in with SparkMLLib

Tags: python, cross-validation, pyspark

I am having trouble accessing the parameters of estimators of model in SparkMLlib. More precisely my problem is: 
I have a logistic regression model for which I want to find the best regularization parameters (`regParam` and `elasticNetParam`). To do that, I use the `CrossValidator` which works and finds me a model better than all the other one I tried. The issue is that I do not know how to access the actual value of the parameters that were found by the cross validator. Below is the code I use to fit my cross validator:

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

lr_predictor = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='polyFeatures', labelCol='label', maxIter=10)
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(lr_predictor.elasticNetParam, [0., 0.5, 1]) \
    .addGrid(lr_predictor.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
    .build()
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=LogRegPipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                          numFolds=2) 
cvModel = crossval.fit(train_set)
bestModel = cvModel.bestModel
# How to get the best parameters fitted by cvModel
```

Comment: Did you try `bestModel.extractParamMap()`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most elegant solution but you can use the following to at least zip together evaluation metrics and hyper parameters

```
zip(cvModel.avgMetrics, paramGrid)
```